# The input value of false for FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN

Tags: php, boolean, filter-var

I want the input to accpet 'true' or 'false' only, so I am trying to use `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` to do that,

```
if (!filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) 
{
    $error = true;
    echo 'error';
}
```

It echoes the error message but it should not.

How can I make it right?

Comment: `'false'` is not a boolean, it's a string.

Comment: `'false'` should be just `false` in this case otherwise it will be treated as a string.

Comment: it still returns the error message with `false`...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Your syntax/usage is correct. [`filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)`](http://php.net/filter_var) however does not verify the pattern, it converts the input string into the accordingly typed value.

To make it explicit:

```
var_dump(filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

Returns the boolean `false`
.

```
var_dump(filter_var('true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

Returns the boolean `true`
.

```
var_dump(filter_var('wrong', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

Returns `NULL`.
That's why I added the second option. The input string does neither classify as `true` nor `false`.

So you actually have to check with `=== NULL` for your condition. That would give you the result you probably desired:

```
if (filter_var('false', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE) === NULL) 
{
    echo "Input did not evaluate to boolean 'false' nor 'true'"
```

Comment: The conclusion was wrong though. You do need `=== NULL` to check for the incorrect input.